# How do I set the same profile to every user on a domain?

Tags: windows, user-profiles

I need to set the user variables and settings for every user in a domain when configuring the workstation for a client.

The setting preferences are:

1. Advanced performance options - Visual effects for best performances
2. Java Auto update - Option is to be disabled or unchecked
3. Internet security settings - under Download - Miscellaneous - Display Mixed content should be enabled.
4. User environment variable should be `TEMP=E:\temp`

How do I go about setting them all in a batch?

Answer (score 1):

In a domain environment you would generally use group policy for Windows settings and customised MSI installers (deployed via group policy) to alter settings for 3rd party software such as the Java runtime.

**1.**
According to

windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/84925/jsi-tip-10021-how-can-i-set-the-windows-xp-visual-effects-to-adjust-for-best-performance-using-the-registry.html

you could run this via a logon script:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects" /V VisualFXSetting /T REG_DWORD /F /D 2
```

or set the same setting using a custom ADM in a GPO.

**2.**
There is info about making a custom Java MSI with auto update disabled here:

www.appdeploy.com/packages/detail.asp?id=38

**3.**
According to [the docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457144.aspx) you can set that via group policy.

**4.**
You can set user environment variables in a logon script. The command required will vary depending on the scripting language you use (cmd shell/vbs/kix)

In a DOS batch file it's just:

SET TEMP=E:\Temp

Answer (score 0):

Windows [Unattended mode](http://unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp/) allows to customize such settings. A tool such as [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/) can help too.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542349/how-to-configure-same-profile-for-every-user-in-a-organization). Original answer by Pascal Thivent.